# AWS - Conditionally run a script on EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am looking for a way to conditionally run a script on every existing / new EC2 instances.

For example, in Azure, you can create an Azure Policy that is executed on every existing / new VM, and when a set of conditions apply on that VM, you can deploy a VM extension or run a DSC script.
I am looking for the equivalent service in AWS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html):

> Using **Run Command**, a capability of AWS Systems Manager, you can remotely and securely manage the configuration of your managed instances. A managed instance is any Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) instance or on-premises machine in your hybrid environment that has been configured for Systems Manager. Run Command allows you to automate common administrative tasks and perform one-time configuration changes at scale. You can use Run Command from the AWS Management Console, the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI), AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell, or the AWS SDKs.
>
> Administrators use Run Command to perform the following types of tasks on their managed instances: install or bootstrap applications, build a deployment pipeline, capture log files when an instance is removed from an Auto Scaling group, and join instances to a Windows domain.

You will need to trigger the Run Command to execute on nominated EC2 instances. It will *not* automatically run for every 'new' instance.

Alternatively, there is [Evaluating Resources with AWS Config Rules - AWS Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/evaluate-config.html):

> Use **AWS Config** to evaluate the configuration settings of your AWS resources. You do this by creating AWS Config rules, which represent your ideal configuration settings. While AWS Config continuously tracks the configuration changes that occur among your resources, it checks whether these changes violate any of the conditions in your rules. If a resource violates a rule, AWS Config flags the resource and the rule as noncompliant.
>
> For example, when an EC2 volume is created, AWS Config can evaluate the volume against a rule that requires volumes to be encrypted. If the volume is not encrypted, AWS Config flags the volume and the rule as noncompliant. AWS Config can also check all of your resources for account-wide requirements. For example, AWS Config can check whether the number of EC2 volumes in an account stays within a desired total, or whether an account uses AWS CloudTrail for logging.

You can create an AWS Config custom rule that triggers a process when a non-compliant resource is found. This way, an automated action could correct the situation.

Comment: Thanks John.
I did some exploration and understood that I can define a AWS Config rule that evaluates if the EC2 instance is compliant or not, and when it's not, I can define a remediation action that will run a SSM document script on that instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an AWS managed service such as [OpsWorks](https://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/) (Managed Chef/Puppet).
This can give you a way of running the commands in an organized way by allowing you to create defined sets of instances and associated resources.